# Дублирование шаблонов Django

Tags: python, html, django

Создал проект с несколькими приложениями (`auth`, `blog`). В каждом приложении создал папку `templates`. Но `base.html` для этих приложений одинаковый. Не хочется дублировать `html` код несколько раз, если какой-то другой вариант?

Comment: Просто создайте один base.html в каком-то одном приложении и всё, другие приложения будут его видеть

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Шаблоны можно наследовать из соседнего приложения, также как и из текущего. Следующая запись будет справедлива для шаблона в приложении `blog` и для шаблона в приложении `auth`, если `base.html` находится в папке `blog`:

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
```

Но я помещаю шаблоны в общую директорию в корне проекта, мне кажется это более очевидным и удобным. Для этого нужно добавить путь к директории в `settings.py`:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        ...
        "DIRS": [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")],
        ...
    },
]
```

Пример структуры директории `templates`:

```
templates
├── blog
│   ├── post_creation.html
│   ├── post_detail.html
│   ├── post_list.html
│   ├── post_multiple_creation.html
│   └── post_multiple_creation_success.html
├── auth
│   ├── logged_out.html
│   ├── login.html
│   ├── profile_edit.html
│   ├── profile.html
│   ├── registration.html
│   └── registration_success.html
├── 403.html
└── base.html
```